# angular 4 Datepicker css issue

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate [ng-bootsrap datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) with angular 4.3.3 and 
Bootstrap:3.3.7

The issue is when I click on the button the CSS of the datepicker that pops up is completely wrong.Also, the date that I pass to the ngModel is not reflected on the picker or input.

The date doesn't come in the input and the picker is not correct.
     twitter Date looks like this

```
{
    year: utcDate.getFullYear(),
    month: utcDate.getUTCMonth() + 1,
    day: utcDate.getUTCDate()
};
```

Below is the HTML of the input

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="twitterTime" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

Below is the screenshot of the issue
[image]

if anyone has faced this issue then please guide.
Thanks!

Comment: ng-bootstrap use Bootstrap 4.0.0-alfa NOT Bootstrap 3.3.7. You must replace the bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

To change bootstrap.css if you use angular-cli you must add in the file angular-cli.json (in "styles")

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.4.4.0.min.css"
  ],
```